# How can I load firestore data multiple times in one widget builder?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Before I write my code down, my firestore has structure like this :

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

As shown in the image, each topic has 'left' and 'right' those have list of posts.
What I want to do is showing the contents of the selected topic and posts in one screen.

Here, I made a code in one State class.

```
class _arenaState extends State<arena> {


  List<int> left_like_state = left_like;
  List<int> left_liked_state = left_liked;
  double vs_left = versus[0]/(versus[0]+versus[1]);
  double vs_right = versus[1]/(versus[0]+versus[1]);
  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      String received_id = widget.data_send;
      final documentStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('topic').doc(received_id).snapshots();
    String title = '';
    String abstract = '';
    String writer = '';
    List<dynamic> left = [] ;
    List<dynamic> right = [] ;
    List<String> content_left=[];
    List<String> writer_left=[];
    List<String> reference_left=[];
    List<int> like_left=[];
    List<int> shared_left=[];

    List<String> content_right=[];
    List<String> writer_right=[];
    List<String> reference_right=[];
    List<int> like_right=[];
    List<int> shared_right=[];

    Future<void> load_lefts(list_posts) async{
      content_left=[];
      writer_left=[];
      like_left=[];
      shared_left=[];
      reference_left=[];
      Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds : 10), (){

      for(int i=0;i<list_posts.length;i++)
        {
          String id_post = left[i];
          FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('post')
              .doc(id_post)
              .get()
              .then((DocumentSnapshot doc) {
              final data_ = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
              content_left.add(data_['content']);
              writer_left.add(data_['writer']);
              reference_left.add(data_['reference']);
              like_left.add(data_['like']);
              shared_left.add(data_['shared']);

              }
              );
        }
      });

    }
    Future<void> load_rights(list_posts) async{
      content_right=[];
      writer_right=[];
      like_right=[];
      shared_right=[];
      reference_right=[];
      print(list_posts.length);
      print('######%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%');
      Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds : 10), (){
        for(int i=0;i<list_posts.length;i++)
        {
          String id_post = right[i];
          print(id_post);
          print('######');
          FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('post')
              .doc(id_post)
              .get()
              .then((DocumentSnapshot doc) {
            final data_ = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
            print(data_);
            content_right.add(data_['content']);
            writer_right.add(data_['writer']);
            reference_right.add(data_['reference']);
            like_right.add(data_['like']);
            shared_right.add(data_['shared']);
            print('inside func');
            print(content_right);
            print(reference_right);

          }
          );
        }

      });
    }
    Future<void> load_posts() async{
      Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds : 10), () => load_lefts(left));
      Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds : 10), () => load_rights(right));
      print(content_left);
      print(content_right);

    }
    return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
        stream: documentStream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Text("Loading");
        }
        var data = snapshot.data! as DocumentSnapshot<Map<String,dynamic>>;
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
          print('available data');
          // get course document
          title = data.data()!['title'];
          abstract = data.data()!['abstract'];
          writer = data.data()!['writer'];
          left = data.data()!['left'];
          right = data.data()!['right'];
          //load_posts().then((value){Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 10));});
//          Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds : 100), () => load_posts());
          // get sections from the document
        }

    return Scaffold(
      ...
    child: Row(
      children:[

      ListView.builder(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
                        itemCount: left.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context,index){
                          Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds : 0), () => load_lefts(left)).then((value){
                            print(content_left);
                            print('000000000000000000000');
                          });

                          return GestureDetector(...);}),
     ListView.builder(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
                        itemCount: right.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context,index){
                          return GestureDetector(...);})
]
    )
)
```

I tried to find the best place and way to call `load_posts()` or `load_left(), load_right()` and failed to load the data. Printing the lists only shows me `[]` ,
and the screen I can see is :

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

I donot understand what mistake I made or whethere I sustain the data structure of firestore.
I could not find why firestore loading fails in this case.
Anybody please help me.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ej2by.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uwu6h.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/siD3s.png

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved :

I made a new Streambuilder class for each listview.builder, instead of reading whole data in one stateful class.

```
Widget customCardPost(BuildContext context, String postId) {
    double width_screen = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final documentStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('post').doc(postId).snapshots();
    return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
        stream: documentStream,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return Text("Loading");
      }
      if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.active) {
        return Text("Connect state is bad.");
      }
      var data = snapshot.data! as DocumentSnapshot<Map<String,dynamic>>;
      print(' post loading... '+postId );
      print(data.data()!);
      // if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
      String content = data.data()!['content'];
      String reference = data.data()!['reference'];
      String writer = data.data()!['writer'];
      int like = data.data()!['like'];
      int shared = data.data()!['shared'];

      return GestureDetector(onTap: ()=> _showDialog(content, writer,like,shared),
        child:
        Card(
            child: ClipPath(
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border(
                    right: BorderSide(color: Colors.amberAccent, width: 5),
                  ),
                ),
                child: ListTile(
                  title:Text(abbreviate_text(content)),
                  subtitle: Text(writer),
                ),

              ),
            )
        ),
      );
    });

  }
```

and the item is listview is :

```
ListView.builder(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
                        itemCount: left.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context,index){
                          Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds : 0), () => load_lefts(left)).then((value){
                            print(content_left);
                            print('000000000000000000000');
                          });

                          return customCardPost(context, left[index])}),
```